# Determining if an operator is linear.

Tags: partial-derivative

How do I determine linearity for the operator $L = x\partial_x + y\partial_y$?

I know the the definition of a linear operator, but I'm not sure what to do with $\partial_x$ and $\partial_y$ and there doesn't seem to be any mapping?

Comment: There is a mapping from the function $f$ to another function $L(f)$ which the latter function is defined by $L(f)(x,y)=x\partial_{x}f(x,y)+y\partial_{y}f(x,y)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{align*}
(x\partial_{x}+y\partial_{y})(f+g)&=x\partial_{x}(f+g)+y\partial_{y}(f+g)\\
&=x\partial_{x}(f)+x\partial_{x}(g)+y\partial_{y}(f)+y\partial_{y}(g)\\
&=(x\partial_{x}+y\partial_{y})(f)+(x\partial_{x}+y\partial_{y})(g),
\end{align*}
can you do the scalar multiple case?